# tmap package: making multiple tm_text() colors dependent on same tm_fill() value

Tags: r, tmap

The code first:

```
library(tmap)
library(tmaptools)

data("Europe")

# subset just three countries for illustration
threeC <- Europe[Europe$sovereignt %in% c("Germany", "Poland", "Ukraine"), ]

tm_shape(threeC) +
  tm_polygons() +
  tm_shape(threeC) +
  tm_borders() +
  tm_fill("pop_est",
          palette = get_brewer_pal("YlGnBu"),
          legend.show = F,
          style = "order") +
  tm_text("sovereignt", size = .8) +
  tm_shape(threeC) +
  tm_text("pop_est", size = .8, auto.placement = .1)
```

The result is:
[image: 3 countries with text labels]

Question 1: Is it possible to show the "pop_est" figures in the map in millions with 2 decimal places like: 82.32m, 38.48m, 45.70m by using some formula within tm_text() function (ie, without creating another custom column in the dataframe and then using it instead of "pop_est")?

Question 2: The color of text showing country names is either black or white (here "Germany" is printed in white and other two country names are printed in black) depending on the fill color which greatly helps visibility in large maps. But the color of additional text showing "pop_est" figures is always black. How to make it also black or white depending on the fill color to aid visibility?

Answer (score 0):

Answer 1: After some experimentation, it seems like there is no way to do it without creating a custom column beforehand:

```
threeC$pop_est.m <- (threeC$pop_est/1e6) %>% sprintf("%.2f", .) %>% paste0("m")
```

Answer 2: use another `tm_fill` function with all previous options and addtionally make it transparent by `alpha = 0`.

Thus the revised code would be:

```
library(tmap)
library(tmaptools)

data("Europe")

# subset just three countries for illustration
threeC <- Europe[Europe$sovereignt %in% c("Germany", "Poland", "Ukraine"), ]
threeC$pop_est.m <- (threeC$pop_est/1e6) %>% sprintf("%.2f", .) %>% paste0("m")

tm_shape(threeC) +
  tm_polygons() +
  tm_shape(threeC) +
  tm_borders() +
  tm_fill("pop_est",
          palette = get_brewer_pal("YlGnBu"),
          legend.show = F,
          style = "order") +
  tm_text("sovereignt", size = .8) +
  tm_shape(threeC) +
  tm_fill("pop_est",
          palette = get_brewer_pal("YlGnBu"),
          legend.show = F,
          style = "order",
          alpha = 0) + # make it transparent
  tm_text("pop_est.m", size = .8, auto.placement = .1)
```

which will give the desired result:
[image: custom map]